# Express - Session cannot set session variable after response has been sent?

Tags: node.js, session, express, session-variables

In my code time wise, `res.send` is called before setting a session variable(`req.session.variable`) is set in `express-session`. Something like this

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  FB.api('/', function(fbResponse) {
    req.session.variable = 100;
  });
  res.send('test');
});
```

Now this, won't set the variable. Is it a bug or is there some logical reason as to why `express-session` doesn't allow the above? If so, can you please give a counter example where it can be misused?

Comment: use `res.send` inside the callback from the FB.api - else you send the response before you receive one from FB

Comment: @tymeJV : I do not mind sending the response before I get it from FB as such it's not a priority response. But it's pretty inconvenient as I cannot save the session variable after the response has been sent :-(

Answer (score 4):

As @tymeJV said:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  FB.api('/', function(fbResponse) {
    req.session.variable = 100;
    res.send('test');
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, I pretty much have to +1 this :)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others the session should be set before the response as follows

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  FB.api('/', function(fbResponse) {
    req.session.variable = 100;
    res.send('test');
  });
});
```

But I was wondering why not set it after the response, why won't `express-session` allow the same. Well I found that some of the `req.session` functions are pointless after the response and hence ,might create confusions in huge codes . e.g. `req.session.regenerate` is pointless after the response, as such the cookies have been sent. But I guess, express-session is not mature enough to have different categories for such functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two callback functions executing asynchronously: *function(req, res)* and *function(fbResponse)*. Your *res.send('test')* line is being executed before the *function(fbResponse)* is completed (since this is an async function). If you want to ensure the session variable is set before writing your res you should move the *res.send('test')* line inside the inner callback function in your code as explained in other answers.